# VBA Remove duplicates from rows

Tags: vba, excel

The problem is fairly simple, yet i can't find a solution.
I want to remove duplicates per row in a fairly long excel sheet

my code looks like this but doesn't work:

```
Sub delete()

Dim i As Long, j As Integer
i = 1
j = 2
While Sheets("Test").Cells(i, 1).Value <> "end"
    While Sheets("Test").Cells(i, j).Value <> ""
        If Sheets("Test").Cells(i, j) <> Sheets("Test").Cells(i, j).offset(, 1) Then
            j = j + 1
        Else
            Sheets("Test").Cells(i, j).offset(, 1).Clear
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Wend
i = i + 1
Wend
```

End Sub

at the bottom of Column A is the word end, the data to be sorted out is in the columns B to QC. Some rows have duplicates, some don't.
In the next step I need to gather the non duplicate Values in column B seperated by a comma. Can anybody provide me help?

Images:

[Current datastructure](http://picload.org/image/iwgoicp/now.jpg)

[After deletion of the Duplicates](http://picload.org/image/iwglcdc/afterdelete.jpg)

Comment: what is the problem exactly? your code throws an error, doesn't work as expected? ...

Comment: It simply does nothing

Comment: you didn't provide enough arguments to removeduplicates (according to msdn)
try: `ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i, "QC" & i).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(2,3), Header:=xlYes` I don't know if you have a header. But try if this removes duplicates of the columns B and C or wherever you know duplicates are

Comment: Sub delete()
Dim i As Long
i = 1

    While Sheets("Test").Cells(i, 1).Value <> "end"
        Sheets("Test").Range("B" & i, "QC" & i).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(2, 3), Header:=xlNo
        i = i + 1
        
    Wend

End Sub

Now and it still does nothing.

Comment: could you please provide a screenshot of your data (few columns are enough) so i can test it.

Comment: let me confirm, what you want to remove, duplicate row or duplicate cells?

Comment: Cells row by row

Picture: http://picload.org/image/iwgoicp/now.jpg

Comment: does it work when you mark the cells on the sheet and use the `remove duplicate` function on the ribbon? and record the macro too. If Excel says: "no duplicates found" your code isn't wrong I guess

Comment: No matter what i do it doesn't work 0.o AS it seems the ribbon button tries to to delete duplicates from columns not range or rows. that's what I believe at least.

Comment: That's the reason why @Nicolas asked what you want to remove. because `remove duplicates` checks the content of the columns.
for example: you have "28 mm" in 3 columns. If you remove duplicates with these 3 columns as basis. Excel will delete all rows which have "28 mm" as value -> deleting the "height" information from all articles which have "28 mm" as height, except the first one

Comment: Can you provide an alternative?

Comment: probably, but you have to tell us what you want to delete exactly. the best is you provide us a screenshot example what the result after the code execution shall be

Comment: First delete the duplicates from the sample data above

http://picload.org/image/iwglcdc/afterdelete.jpg

than join the remaining values seperated by comma

http://picload.org/image/iwglcdp/final.jpg

This is what I'm looking for

Comment: is it possible for you to edit your question and post the pictures there?

Comment: not enough points to post pictures yet, sorry :-( But I can post the links there :-)

Comment: this is also a solution, but you should reupload it somewhere else, because these pics are blocked at my current location. otherwise i'm able to help in approx. 12 hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub DeleteRows()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim wsTemp As Worksheet
Dim v As Variant

Set wsTemp = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

With Sheets("Test")
    LastRow = .Range("A:A").Find(what:="end", after:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Row

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        LastCol = .Cells(i, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If LastCol > 1 Then
            v = .Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, LastCol).Value
            .Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, LastCol).ClearContents
            wsTemp.Range("A:A").Clear
            wsTemp.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(v, 2), 1).Value = Application.Transpose(v)
            wsTemp.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(v, 2), 1).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
            v = wsTemp.Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Value
            .Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, UBound(v, 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(v)
        End If
    Next
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wsTemp.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: As awesome as this looks, I get an error at this line:

wsTemp.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(v, 2), 1).Value = Application.Transpose(v)

Type mismatch

Comment: What is the value of UBound(v,2) when you get the error?

Comment: It is probably in a row with only 1 entry, ie a value in column A and nothing to the right of it. Maybe just add a condition to check if LastCol = 1 then skip that row.

Comment: the value of Ubound(v,2) is <type mismatch>. To be totally honest: I don't even understand the code below the LastCol=.Cells(i, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column.
Where would you put that If condition?

Comment: Figured it out myself, I still get an error every few lines because of unknown reasons. I just restart the Macro and the error pops up at a later point. it's mostly empty rows that seem to cause troubles and most of the time its the .Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, UBound(v, 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(v) which is causing troubles

sometimes i look at the values and there is no evidence of any error at all

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are awesome!

Comment: You're welcome. If you are happy with my answer, please accept it by clicking the tick next to it.